# Is there a "single-user" OAuth option for Instagram?

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, instagram, signpost

I'm developing a Java application that will display Instagram content.  It's for an installation, and will only ever authenticate as a single user.  I'm trying to keep my OAuth consumer code as simple as possible.

Twitter offers a "single-user" OAuth implementation that seems quite a bit simpler than the standard "OAuth dance".  Is there anything analogous for Instagram?

If not, are there any other shortcuts to getting up and running with OAuth + Instagram?  I'm using Apache HTTP Components (specifically, [Fluent](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fluent.html), to ease asynchronous communication) and looking into using [OAuth Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/).  However, the path to Fluent+Signpost isn't immediately obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was barking up the wrong tree.  Turns out I don't need authentication for the requests my desktop application makes, only need to [pass the client_id](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

There's a limit per hour on the number of requests per client_id; for applications with multiple users, it makes much more sense to authenticate so that limit shifts to per-user (via OAuth access token), but for my single-user single-install application that's not necessary.